# got error while fetching an image

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have faced this error:

> Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error I got in 3rd override function in cell declaration
>
> Could not cast value of type 'UICollectionViewCell' (0x10d27aa18) to 'collection.viewcell' (0x10a431130).

```
extension PhotoCollectionViewController {

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

        return searches.count
    }

    //2
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                                 numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return searches[section].searchResults.count
    }

    //3
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! viewcell
        //2
        let flickrPhoto = photoForIndexPath(indexPath: indexPath)
        print(flickrPhoto)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        //3
        //cell.imageview.image = flickrPhoto.thumbnail
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: what the error u faced and `let flickrPhoto = photoForIndexPath(indexPath: indexPath) this vary from earches[section].searchResults.count`

Comment: @Rathna Please add some details about what you want and what is the problem you faced.

Comment: Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error i got in 3rd overide function in cell declaration

Comment: Could not cast value of type 'UICollectionViewCell' (0x10d27aa18) to 'collection.viewcell' (0x10a431130).

Comment: `viewcell` is a custom cell class?

Comment: yes it is a custom class

Comment: The first character of a class in Swift should be uppercased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the **viewcell** to **UICollectionViewCell**

```
 let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell
```

If you want to use custom cell the first register and use.
Make sure **registerClass** and **dequeueReusableCell** are the same class to solve the problem.

```
self.registerClass(viewcell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! viewcell
```

This will help.